# How To Get the Sum of a Column within a given Date range in a Table and Update a particular Cell in The Table with The Sum in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Table named `PersonalLedgerForTheiftFundAndShareClone`
I want to get The Sum Of `TInterest` **(** *TheiftFundInterest* **)** within The Date Range Of `2014-03-31 00:00:00.000` To `2015-03-31 00:00:00.000` For each Employee and Then Update The `TInterest` with The Sum Where Date is `2015-03-31 00:00:00.000` For that Specific Employee.

I Have Written a Stored Procedure To accomplish This Task But Not Able To Get The Desired Result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTheiftFundInterest   
AS 
DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(50), @var3 CURSOR, @var4 INT
SET @var1 = 0;
SET @var3 = CURSOR FOR
SELECT EmNo FROM [WBSEB].[dbo].[PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone]
OPEN @var3
FETCH NEXT
FROM @var3 INTO @var1
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @var4 = 0;

SELECT @var4=SUM(TInterest)
FROM [WBSEB].[dbo].[PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone]
WHERE TDate >= '2014-03-31 00:00:00.000' AND TDate <= '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
AND EmNo = @var1

UPDATE [WBSEB].[dbo].[PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone]
SET TInterest = @var4
Where TDate = '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' AND EmNo = @var1

FETCH NEXT
FROM @var3 INTO @var1
END

CLOSE @var3
DEALLOCATE @var3
GO
```

Can Anyone Tell me What I am Doing Wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a cursor, to start with...
I would go with an update statement using a join to a derived table.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE t1
SET TInterest = SumTInterest
FROM PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT EmNo, SUM(TInterest) AS SumTInterest
    FROM PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone
    WHERE TDate >= '2014-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
    AND TDate <= '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
    GROUP BY EmNo
) t2
ON(t1.EmNo = t2.EmNo)
WHERE TDate = '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000'
```

**Note:** Code was written directly here, there might be some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to avoid cursors and use a inner join tables update ...

```
UPDATE p
SET TInterest = x.ST
FROM [PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone] p INNER JOIN 
(SELECT SUM(z.TInterest) ST, z.EmNo
FROM [PersonalLedgerForTFundAndShareClone] z
WHERE z.TDate >= '2014-03-31 00:00:00.000' AND z.TDate <= '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY z.EmNo) x ON p.EmNo = x.EmNo
WHERE p.TDate = '2015-03-31 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because when you declare the cursor you are not getting a distinct list of employee numbers, so you end up iterating over the same employee multiple times.